# Get new items from rss feed

Tags: python-3.x, rss, feedparser, hashlib, hash-function

I am using python feedparser to parse some rss feeds(every 2 hours), unfortunately the rss feeds do not contain etag or modified values and therefore whenever I parse the feeds I get the entire data everytime. I am thinking of creating a hash of entries returned from feedparser.parse and store that in the database, so that next time when I parse again I can compare against the hash and see if feed has changed and only then kick off parsing for each item in the feed
My questions

1. Is there any other/better way to see if rss feed has updated
2. How do I create the hash? Is it enough to just do the following

   ```
   import hashlib 
   hash_object = hashlib.sha256(<FEEDPARSER_RESPONSE>)
   hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
   ```
3. Store the hex_dig in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's plausible to hash the FEEDPARSER_RESPONSE, especially if the etag or modified values don't exist in your feed. You didn't provide the link for your RSS feed, so I'm using one from CNN for my answer.

```
import hashlib
import feedparser

cnn_top_news = feedparser.parse('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss')

# I using entries, because in testing it gave me the same hash.
news_updated = cnn_top_news.entries

###################################################################
# During testing all of these items worked for creating the hash.
# So there are multiple options to choice from.   
#
# cnn_top_news['entries']
# titles = [entry.title for entry in cnn_top_news['entries']]
# summaries = [entry.summary for entry in cnn_top_news['entries']]
###################################################################

hash_object = hashlib.sha256(str(news_updated).encode('utf-8'))
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()

print (hex_dig)
# output 
371c5730c7f1407878a32a814bc72542b48a43e1f7670eae0627d2617289161b
```

Comment: Actually I just noticed intermittently for some of the feeds I get different hash when running feedparser, I thought it might be because the entries are getting reordered or something, so I added ```sorted_entries = sorted(rss_entries, key=lambda k: str(k.get('id',0)))
            hash_object = hashlib.sha256(str(sorted_entries).encode('utf-8'))
            hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()``` but even that has not helped

Comment: Is rss_entries a single feed?

Comment: Yes. ```feed_response = feedparser.parse('http://feeds.rsc.org/rss/ob')
rss_entries = feed_response.entries```

Comment: Example of feeds with issue- "http://feeds.rsc.org/rss/cp","http://feeds.rsc.org/rss/ob","http://feeds.rsc.org/rss/cc"

Comment: How long does it take for the problem to occur?  I'm asking because, I'm running a test of those 3 feeds.

Comment: My parsers run every 2 hours

Comment: Ok.  I'll need some time to run the test on my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188357/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-prim).